# Getting per-module memory stats?

Tags: 7

I'm hosting Drupal on Dreamhost shared hosting where I have a maximum of 90 MB RAM and a lot of enabled modules.
Is there a way to see how much memory each module is using?

Comment: Accepting Berdir's answer due to completeness and it seems like the most standard way of doing things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this is not possible. The used memory of a module is scattered among many functions, caches, etc.

There are tools which allow you to display the memory usage per function, how much time a function used, and so on; for example, there are [XHProf](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html) and [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), but both are PHP extensions and you will not be able to install them on a shared host.

You could, however, create a local installation (if you haven't already) and then check these tools out. [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) integrates nicely with XHProf, so you only need to install the extension, and enable the corresponding checkbox in the configuration settings of Devel.

Comment: devel and xhprof play nicely together on D6 as well.

Comment: and on Windows!

Comment: and if you have a Dreamhost VPS with root access (like I do) you can pretty much do anything you want, like compiling your own PHP and installing XHProf.

Answer (score 7):

Pounard does have an [experimental module](http://drupal.org/project/profiling) for that.

I already talk with him, he knows that this is highly experimental and you really should make a backup of your data before trying this module.

Maybe that could help.